# ArcGIS Runtime .NET does not make a GetLegendGraphic request

Tags: wms, legend, arcgis-runtime, getlegendgraphic

I'm using ArcGIS runtime SDK .NET to populate maps with WMS Layers

This is a bit strange. If I load a WMSLayer on the map without specifying any layer, I see how it starts to recover all the legends of the server, one by one. On the contrary, if I specify which layers I need (setting field Layer) I see that it adds the layer to the map, but does not make the request to read the legend

If Layers object is empty:

- Do a GetCapabilities request
- Do one GetLegendGraphic request per layer
- Do a GetMap request

But if I set Layers object

- Do a GetCapabilities request
- Do a GetMap request

In both cases ShowLegend is true

Comment: I edited your title, because it didn't make sense, a WMS layer never makes a GetLegendGraphic request, only a client can make such a request.